# Is creating view using REST API and x query same in marklogic?? Can i use them to sql query?

Tags: schema, marklogic

While trying to create views in SQL data modeling,  the documentation says to use REST API using curl. they also provided creating schema and view using XQuery. Are both same?? Or if they are different, how can I differentiate them

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the documentation you're already referring to, but there's a good guide for [getting started using SQL](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql) on MarkLogic. XQuery and the REST API are not the same thing. The REST API is one way to configure/use the MarkLogic database without having to know/use XQuery. Without more specific questions, it's hard to help you here.